# Como adicionar parametro no nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

sou iniciante em dev e gostaria de saber como passar um parametro via função. Por exemplo:

```js
function hello(name) {
     console.log("hello " + name);
}
hello("Fulano");
```

Se eu rodar **node hello**, ele vai me retornar "Hello Fulano".

Entrentanto eu gostaria de passar o parâmetro junto com a função. Ou seja, eu quero executar **node hello Fulano** e quero q ele me retorne "Hello Fulano". Como proceder?

Comment: Os parâmetros passados estão no objeto `process.argv`, dê uma olhada nele.. não via passar direto pra function, mas você pode ler e chamar a function

Answer (score 1):

Basta utilizar [process.argv[2]](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html). Essa propriedade irá armazenar uma cópia, somente leitura, do valor original de `argv[0]` passado quando o `arquivo.js` for iniciado.

```
function hello(name) {
     console.log("hello " + name);
}
hello( process.argv[2] );
```

Depois é só executar: `node file.js Seu-Nome`

Para ler outros parâmetros, você pode usar o `for`, por exemplo:

```
function hello(name) {
     console.log("hello " + name);
}

for (let i = 2; i < process.argv.length; i++) {
    hello( process.argv[i] );
}
```

Depois é só executar: `node file.js Seu-Nome-1 Seu-Nome-2 Seu-Nome-3`

Comment: `process.argv.slice(2).forEach(nome => hello(nome))` fica legal também xD

Comment: @nbkhope também ^^

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal.